# Implementing admin APIs for dynamic client management in Spring Security Authorization Server

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I'm currently working on a project that involves implementing a Spring Security Authorization Server for OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect protocols. One of the requirements is to create a set of admin APIs similar to those provided by Keycloak, which allow dynamic management of clients.

I would like to know how I can go about implementing these admin APIs in my Spring Security Authorization Server.

I have explored the Spring Security documentation, but I couldn't find any specific guidance on implementing admin APIs for client management. I am seeking recommendations, best practices, or any pointers that could help me achieve this.

What would be the recommended approach for implementing admin APIs in the Spring Security Authorization Server? Are there any existing libraries or modules that can assist in building these admin functionalities? Additionally, how can I integrate these APIs seamlessly into my existing Spring Security Authorization Server configuration?

Comment: This question is fairly broad and hard to answer. Can you please provide some code demonstrating what you've tried so far and more details to narrow the problem down to the issue you're having and what you've tried to resolve it?